# How to construct a multi-tower tensorflow graph from predefined models

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a model that has been trained and stored to file in Tensorflow. It was a pretrained model that had some parameter tweaking done to produce the required results. Now I am looking to take that model and run it in parallel across multiple GPUs for inference.

I can only find resources showing how to produce multi-GPU towers when the graph is initially defined by using `tf.device` when defining the operations, but since I am reading in a GraphDef from file I don't have that option.

For reference, the model loading code (identical to what is on the tensorflow hub's `label_image.py`):

```py
def load_graph(model_file):
  graph = tf.Graph()
  graph_def = tf.GraphDef()

  with open(model_file, "rb") as f:
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
  with graph.as_default():
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)

  return graph
```

Comment: Hi.
I have the same issue.. any idea for solution ?
Thanks.